# Why are (most) solids periodic?

Tags: solid-state-physics, crystals

Is there a rigorous proof that periodic arrangements minimize the energy of a group of particles?

Comment: The title of the question is not particularly clear or even true.  Many solids are [amorphous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amorphous_solid), and what does it mean for "most" solids to be periodic? On the other hand, the body of the question is indeed interesting physics!

Comment: Indeed the title is not really concise, but I think is true to an extend. It is clear that perfect crystals does not exist (forbidden by entropy, which will give rise to vacancies in the structure ans such), but the theory derived assuming the existence of such a periodicity agrees with experiments. When I wrote "most", I thought about [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasicrystal) quasicrystals.

Comment: What I mean is this: most solids in a pasta bowl are amorphous. "Most" is a statistical term which has no intrinsic meaning until you decide on how to sample the 'space of all solids', and there is no unique or canonical way to do this. Most of the solids considered in undergraduate solid state physics are indeed periodic, but that is only because they are easier to treat.

Comment: Even in graduate courses you assume that your system has periodicity. If this is not the case, things become much more complicated because the band picture breaks down (No Bloch states).

Comment: Yes. But that need not represent the majority of real-world solids. What does that even mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the feeling that there may not be a rigourous proof of the type you describe in your question.

I remember a couple of years ago there was a proof that the close packed structures (ccp / hcp) gave the best 'space filling' characteristics. This proof by [Hales was confirmed in August of 2014](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphere_packing) The proof relies in part on computer checking that other possibilites have lower space filling ratios. Space filling is a measure of how much the space in a volume of a lattice is filled by spheres of fixed radius.

Given that close packed structures have only just proved to be the most efficient way of packing spheres I doubt the rigorous proof you are asking about has been produced.

I would also point out that your question is quite general and does not consider the binding mechanism between particles. In some cases, metals primarily, there may be little of no directionality preferred and the lowest energy structures are most closely packed.
In other solids, such as diamond, the shape of the solid reflects the *very* directional nature of the links between different carbon atoms.